# Formatting an SHA-1 hash like .Net does in Bash

Tags: .net, bash, hash, formatting, sha1

Could someone please explain how the hash.ComputeHash function works in C# .Net.

I am trying to emulate the behavior of a .net hasing program in bash on a mac server, but am getting different results!

.Net Code:

```
 Byte[] z = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("1B-F5");
 string myhash1 = BitConverter.ToString(hash.ComputeHash(z)); 
 string myhash2 = BitConverter.ToString(hash.ComputeHash(hash.ComputeHash(z)));
```

Returns Values :

```
myhash1 = "EF-83-00-69-6F-22-7C-1C-9C-84-C3-66-06-06-A5-12-A0-C7-91-B5"
myhash2 = "D3-5C-95-AD-2D-9E-5A-49-D0-D8-2B-4F-A5-F9-9A-6F-02-EA-8C-83"
```

The problem is I cant get the Second has value (which has been double hashed) in my bash script.

Bash:

```
echo -n "1B-F5" | openssl sha1
```

Gives the correct first hashvalue (minus "-" characters)
however

```
echo -n "1B-F5" | openssl sha1 | openssl sha1
```

Gives a completely different hash. I suspect this is because the C# code is hashing a Byte Array and not a string.

Is there anyway I can get the same output in bash?

Comment: I hope you don't expect the UTF8.GetBytes to return two bytes... Is that the case?

Comment: Also, in terms of the SHA1 algorithm, it's a simple matter to get a tool like ILSpy and just go look at the SHA1 implementation in .NET (it's all located in the mscorlib assembly.

Comment: I'm confused. You are saying `echo -n "1B-F5" | openssl sha1` returns the hash with no '-' symbols. Of course hashing that again will give you a different result if you are not including the '-'s in the second `|openssl sha1`. The C# code is including the '-' separators, your shell script is not.

Comment: If possible, I highly recommend using something other than BitConverter so that you don't have to worry about the `-`s, which are completely unnecessary

Comment: Yes, string representation of a SHA-1 hash is usually just the octets.

Answer (score 2):

Try to convert the second hash step to a string then hash that. See what you get. Remember in this you're also hashing the - octet separators as well.

```
byte[] z = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("1B-F5");
string myhash1 = BitConverter.ToString(hash.ComputeHash(z)); 

z = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(myhash1);
string myhash2 = BitConverter.ToString(hash.ComputeHash(z));
```

Answer (score 0):

If you compare your results to those from [online SHA1 tools](http://www.tools4noobs.com/online_php_functions/sha1/)
You'll see you're hashing the string "1B-F5" correctly. I suspect you're trying to hash a two-byte array.

Another possibility is that you may need to convert the first hash's byte array to string and hash that string